# Is there any way to set a single cache across all mapper files in Mybatis?

Tags: java, mybatis

I am facing the following Mybatis cache problem.

Here is the use-case:

I have 3 Classes `A`, `B` and `C` and `A` class is having has-`A` relationship with `B`  & `C` class. 
There are three mapper files `a.xml`, `b.xml` and `c.xml` for each classes to perform CRUD operations.

Retrieving Class `A` object ,which also includes `B` and `C` in it, by using join query written in `a.xml` file gives stale `B` and `C` object.

I can get rid of this issue by disabling cache in `a.xml` file, i.e. by commenting out the below line in `a.xml` file.

```
<cache />
```

But is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

The cache tag is relevant to namespace.  If all of your mappers have same namespace, then they should share a common cache.

See the [documentation](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/sqlmap-xml.html#cache-ref) for `cache-ref`.